# QnAmaker not listing up my knowledge base and is not even letting me to create a new one

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

Am not able to see the list of my knowledge base already created. The KB was created a week ago and is running fine with the bot webapp. But I cannot make any changes to it as I don't see it listed in the following link https://www.qnamaker.ai/Home/MyServices

So I tried to create a new KB. But it gets stuck in the step two. The 'Azure QnA service' pop down list shows a disabled service listing.
[The grey disabled listing of my service when creating a new KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uznf.png)

Comment: have you tried logging out and logging back in to the qnamaker portal and see if that allows you to select the service?do you get any error on the dev console?did you try hitting the refresh button and then try selecting?

Comment: Yes I tried all of the above but nothing worked. I even changed my browser and cleaned cookie space as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QnA Maker Knowledge Base not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684808/qna-maker-knowledge-base-not-showing-up)

Comment: you can refer to a similar issue is being tracked on Github https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54640

Comment: I think Microsoft team has resolved it and i can see all my KB's